# Setting up Liferay Portal 6.0 from source

Tags: java, liferay, portal

I want to compile and run Liferay portal from the source code. I can set up Liferay, but not from source code and this is important as I want to heavily edit Liferay.

Are there any guides out there how to do this for Liferay 6.0?

Answer (score 3):

In order to have a reasonable chance to upgrade to the next version please consider to use plugins to extend Liferay: Many typical customizations are available in hook plugins, everything is available in the ext plugin.

If your changes are in themes and portlets, they are easily added instead of built-in.

This is well documented in the development guide and really gives you everything you need while separating your changes from Liferay's (in the next version)